# Extract addresses and names from a listing in an HTML page

Tags: java, trim

Okay, so I have printed a pages HTML to string, and I am wanting to grab a certain String from it. The thing is it is different every time I load the page. Example:

> ```
> Blah
> blah
> blah
>
> 1. name
>    address
>    phone number
>
> 2. name
>    address
>    phone number
>
> blah
> blah
> ```

There could be anything from 1 to 10 listings.
All I'm interested in is grabbing **address** and **name**.

I did try:

```
 public static String removeNonDigits(final String str) {
      if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
           return "";
      }
       return str.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
 }
```

But with no Avail.

Comment: Have you tried to extract the data from HTML with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

Comment: No need for `str.length() ==0` now that we have [`String#isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--). And it seems you wanna remove all the digits, by the look of your `replaceAll` method. Is that what you're trying to do? Also, `+` is for "*one or more*"; if you want "*0 or more*", use `*`. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, though; you didn't give a good example.

Comment: To follow up on @user3707125, take one step back and don't print the HTML to a string, but instead walk the DOM to find the `<li>` or whatever that make up the numbered list. European phone numbers, for example, are often `.`-separated, which may confuse a regex search.

Comment: Edit: changed title to represent the underlying requirement

Answer (score 0):

Might have to adjust a little I don't know where the whitespaces are exactly:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\n *(?:[1-9]|10)\\. +(.+?) *\\n *(.+?) *\\n");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println("name: " + matcher.group(1));
  System.out.println("address: " + matcher.group(2));
  System.out.println(matcher.group()); // the whole match
}
```